# White tooltip with white arrow visible on white backgound

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tooltip

I am trying to display a white tooltip with a white arrow. Something similar to this:

[image: tooltip example]

It works fine for other colors please see the code provided, but not for the white color. I understand that the white color is simply not visible on the white background but what is the best way to make it stand out?

```js
$(function () {
  $('#tooltip').tooltip('show');
});
```

```css
#tooltip, {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}
.tooltip-inner {
  background: #fff;
}
.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow { 
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<label for="epcfLevel3Name" class="col-md-5 required">button<span id="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign pull-right"></span></label>
```

Comment: Please add the missing `<script>` tags for jQuery and whichever library you are using to provide the `.tooltip()` function.

Comment: Your updated code still does not contain whichever library is adding support for the `.tooltip` function. Please add that script tag as well.

Comment: I believe it should work with Jquery only. no other libraries are required.

Comment: I've updated your code above as a live snippet, and as you can see if you attempt to run it, it does not work. That snippet needs to work and produce a tooltip before we can assist in troubleshooting the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the snippet is that the external css is being applied after the inline css, so you must use `!important` to override it.

Here is a style close to your screenshot:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#tooltip').tooltip('show');
});
```

```css
.tooltip-inner::before {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: -2px -2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4);
  content: "\00a0";
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -1px;
  transform: rotate( 45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate( 45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate( 45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate( 45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate( 45deg);
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  color: #000 !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #B2B2B2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<label for="epcfLevel3Name" class="col-md-5 required">button<span id="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign pull-right"></span></label>
```

Comment: hi thank you for your answer really helpful. will this code also work for the top left and right tooltips?

Comment: The concept remains the same, I guess, you'll need adopt style for each side.

Comment: can you please give me an idea about the parameters I should try to play with? I see it works but I am not sure I can understand your approach.